# How to interpret 見ても in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning

> “それありき”で、あとから選手を選んでんじゃないか？ と。『Aブロック、10人選ばなきゃいけない』『じゃあ、まあしょうがないけど“コイツ”入れておこうか？』みたいな。なんかそういうのを凄く感じますよね、今年の最終リーグ戦を**見ても**。だから『そうじゃないだろう』と（言いたい）。

In the context the speaker is talking bad things about the organization of a tournament (リーグ戦). He talks about how they (the organization in charge) select the participants of the tournament and then he says how much he hates it (凄く感じます).
Is there something implied after 見ても?

Comment: I am not sure though, maybe "だから『そうじゃないだろう』と（言いたい)" implies that the speaker wants to say that he is not the one who has been selected for just filling in the tournament.Rather He wants to insist that he is the best player. So "みても" implies that the speaker seeing the member of the tournament and says that some people were chosen just to fill in the vacancy.

Comment: @kimiTanaka What you're saying is correct, he just won the whole tournament and he's talking about other players/wrestlers being put in the tournament just to fill the blocks up. But I still don't understand the meaning of 見ても.

Comment: The organizer is always doing so. So, the wrestler has been fed up with it and see the this year's final league for instance and the same thing happens. Then he says "最終リーグ戦をみても”. I think "も” implies for instance.

Comment: @kimiTanaka so 見ても in this context means "I'm seeing this (same thing happening in this year's リーグ戦) also" ???

Comment: I think so. Seeing or looking back on the match-up in the tournament. Same as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small but important correction - the 凄く感じます here doesn't mean anything about hatred (though there is of course negative feeling implied in the wider context). The 感じます simply has its usual meaning of "feel", and its object is そういうの, which refers back to the content of the previous sentences - the speaker has a strong feeling/intuition that the organisation is choosing the tournament participants in this way.

Your intuition that there should be something after 見ても is correct, but it isn't implied - it's simply been stated earlier in the sentence. This is a form of 倒置法, a grammatical phenomenon where elements in a sentence are reversed for emphasis, or (as is the case here) to better follow the speaker's train of thought.

So the original sentence here would be 今年の最終リーグ戦を見ても、そういうのを凄く感じます, literally something like "Even from looking at this year's final tournament, I strongly get that kind of feeling." The 見て…感じます implies causation (looking at X, I feel Y), and the も indicates that this year's final tournament is just one of many things that makes the speaker feel that this is the case.