# how to analyze this sentence?

Tags: readings

> さて、この目の前の長細い箱のなかみなら、開ける前からわかっている。長ねぎである。夫の実家の畑からやってきた長ねぎ。実家のあるあたりは、深谷ねぎや下仁田ねぎで有名な地**も**ほど近い**の**を見**ても**、ねぎとは相性のいい土壌なのだろうか。どの季節のねぎも、おいしい。

1. how does も in this sentence work?
2. what does の refer to in this sentence?
3. how do ても work in this sentence? since  I don't see two clauses before and after ても contradict eatch other

I don't know whether or not this site allow me to  ask several quesitons under one post,but split them into several posts will be laborious.I will very appreciate to your answer

Answer (score 2):

(I suppose there's a typo: 有名な**土**地)

The easy one is Q2: の is a nominalizer. It is equivalent to ほど近い**こと**を...

As for Q1, も should be the standard *also*, but it is not very clear in addition to what. Putting aside the added meaning, it can be replaced by が: 有名な土地**が**ほど近いのを...

Q3: it is the same as the following question:

- [How to interpret 見ても in this paragraph?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52995/45489)

In the whole sentence, the main structure is 実家のあるあたりは、ねぎとは相性のいい土壌なのだろうか and there is inserted 深谷ねぎや下仁田ねぎで有名な地もほど近いのを見ても、 ('even looking at the fact that..., is the neighborhood good for leeks?').

---

As for Q2 も, one explanation is that the inserted clause as an addition to どの季節のねぎも、おいしい. That is, something like *on top of leeks being very good in all seasons, looking also at the fact that areas of famous leeks are close, is the neighborhood particularly suited to grow leeks?*.

A similar usage:

- テストも近いから一生懸命勉強しなければならない Since the exam is coming, I have to study hard.

Comment: thank you,your answer helps。

Comment: but I think ねぎとは相性のいい土壌なのだろうか here is not to express question but to express guess. so it is better to translated as "ねぎとは相性のいい土壌はずだ"

Comment: @CN.hitori You are right, but 'guess' here is a question to the speaker herself. *I wonder if...*